# Session Expired message in only Https not in Http

Tags: maven, session, tomcat, phantomjs, session-cookies

I am using Java code and MongoDB as server side. I am actually Android developer so not sure about Server side. i have two servers one is for Production and another is QA for internal testing.

In server side we have the following code to check session

```
HttpSession session
if(session.isNew()){
 {
   Throw Session Expired
 }
else
 {
    other tasks need to do
 }
```

The same code we are using in QA and Production but when i call from Android POST call it throws session expired from PROD Link with https(https://www.XXXYYYY.com) but always works in (http://www.QA_XXXXYYY.com)

How can i fix this... 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably unrelated to `phantomjs`?

Comment: ok thanks, i am actually Android developer i don't have much knowledge on Server side. so i added.. anyone is aware about this issue please help me. its some urgent